# SQL Server : Query not running as needed

Tags: sql-server, database

I am working with Sage Evolution and do a lot of the back end stuff to customize it for our company.

I need to write a query where, when a user enters a negative quantity the system must not allow the transaction, however when the user enters a negative quantity and the product belongs to the "chemicals" group it needs to process the transaction.

Here is my code I have written so far.

```
DECLARE 
     @iAfterfQuantity Int;
     @iAfteriStockCodeID Int;
     @iAfterStockItemGroup VarChar

SELECT
    @iAfterfQuantity   = fQuantity,
    @iAfteriStockCodeID  = iStockCodeID
FROM 
    INSERTED

SELECT 
    @iAfterStockItemGroup = ItemGroup 
FROM 
    dbo.stkItem 
WHERE 
    StockLink = @iAfteriStockCodeID

BEGIN
    IF @iAfterfQuantity < 0 AND @iAfterStockItemGroup <> 'chemicals'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

Comment: Biggest flaw I can see here is you are considering that trigger will execute for each row

Answer (score 1):

This is a task better suited for a check constraint then for a trigger, especially considering the fact that you are raising an error.

First, create the check function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_FunctionName
(
    @iAfterfQuantity Int,
    @iAfteriStockCodeID Int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @iAfterStockItemGroup VarChar(150) -- Must specify length!
SELECT @iAfterStockItemGroup = ItemGroup FROM dbo.stkItem WHERE StockLink=@iAfteriStockCodeID

IF @iAfterfQuantity < 0 AND @iAfterStockItemGroup <> 'chemicals'
     RETURN 0

RETURN 1 -- will be executed only if the condition is false...

END
```

Then, alter your table to add the check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
    ADD CONSTRAINT ck_ConstraintName
    CHECK (dbo.fn_FunctionName(fQuantity, iStockCodeID) = 1)
GO
```

Comment: we can not alter the tables

Comment: It's the way evolution was coded, we cannot alter the tables but as you said add triggers, which is what we normally do for clients when we need to access a customer report etc...

Comment: I see. I'll try to come up with an instead of trigger in a few hours (or days, depending on how much pressure there is at work).

Comment: We need a working solution to take to the client by Friday, they are a retail store.

Comment: Then you better work hard on finding one. With all due respect, I don't remember getting payed for answering people on stackoverflow.